# Is category theory more a field of study or a viewpoint on mathematics?

Tags: soft-question, category-theory

I heard a bit about Category Theory, especially when studying topology, although I never really studied it.
I am quite curious about it, in particular I would like if someone could better explain:

-Is category theory a study field in its own interest, like, broadly speaking, Geometry, Analysis, Algebra and so on, or is it more a way of tackling problems any mathematician, independently from his area can embrace? 
Is it a subfield of Logic?
Is it a way to found mathematics (alternative to set theory) ?

-Are there important applications to area of mathematics different from algebra and geometry, such as Analysis, Probability and more applied areas of mathematics, or even other Sciences?

-I really like, for the little I know, the unifying, broadening approach of Category Theory, is it possible to make a career in it, are there programs which specialize in this area? Is it a growing one or a vantage point whose possibility have already been explored?

Comment: category theory is not just about mathematical objects, it is more like a kind of reasoning

Comment: It's a branch of mathematics like any other. A category is a particular kind of structure like rings or topological spaces, etc. The fact that its range of applications is very, very broad lends itself to a particular perspective, but it is not *just* that.

Comment: The [Wikipedia page for category theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category_theory) seems to answer most of your questions. The first piece of advice on https://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask is to do research. As your question is currently formulated it makes it seems that you have done almost no research on this topic of your own. As suggested in the aforementioned page, you should make it clear what research you've done and why it failed to answer your questions.

Comment: @DerekElkins wikipedia doesn't seems to be correct about this topic, I mean: category theory isn't just a branch of mathematics, by example it can be used for linguistics or philosophy, not just mathematics. If you ask me, it is more like a branch of logic than mathematics, or a theory of reasoning.

Comment: @DerekElkins I obviously looked at Wikipedia firstly, although as it Is clear from my question, I am not searching for definitions, but ratherer for hindsight from those who work in this field. Certainly an encyclopedic entry cannot give this kind of info